# react-select is not working inside a accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, react-select

I've Problem that inside accordion my defaultValue is not visible.
If i put it outsite of accorion it works fine.
Is there  any fix?

Buggy Version inside accordion
[image: This is how it looks inside accoridon]

Working Version outside accordion
[image: This is how it looks outside of accordion]

```
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionItem,
  AccordionButton,
  AccordionPanel,
} from '@chakra-ui/accordion';


<Accordion>
<AccordionItem>
    <AccordionButton>
        Settings
    </AccordionButton>
         <AccordionPanel>
             <Select
               key={defaultPayments}
               defaultValue={defaultPayments}
               options={selectPayments}
               isMulti
               theme={infoTheme}
               onChange={setPayments}
               placeholder='Payments'
               components={animatedComponents}
               isSearchable={false}
               noOptionsMessage={() =>
               'No more payments'}
             />
    </AccordionPanel>
<AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

It seems to be about the key prop but i don't know how to fix it so far...